# synchronization primitives: Equal latencies between atomics and mutex lock

Tags: c++, windows, concurrency

I'm trying to improve my understanding of synchronization primitives in C++. I've measured latencies of various concurrent operations, such as:

- For a raw `std::mutex`, the time between `.unlock()` and the return of `.lock()`
- For a `std::condition_variable`, the time between `.notify_one()` and the return of `.wait()`
- For a `std::binary_semaphore`, the time between `.release()` and `.acquire()`
- For a `std::atomic_flag`, the time from `.clear()` and `.notify_one()` to `.wait()` as well as from `.test_and_set()` and `.notify_one()` to `.wait()`

*All* of these latencies are identical (~4µs-15µs). After digging a bit I found that semaphores are implemented with an atomic, and condition_variables boil down to a mutex. So it boils down to atomics vs mutex. When stepping into the relevant functions (on windows/MSVC), I found that atomics use `Wait­On­Address`/`Wake­By­Address` while mutex uses SRW locks (`AcquireSRWLockExclusive`).

Naively I would have assumed atomics (especially atomic_flag) to have the best latency characteristics of all since they're so limited in what they do. So my questions:

- Why are they equally fast? Might be my limited testing.
- What are the differences between `Wait­On­Address`/`Wake­By­Address` and SRW locks? They're both limited to a single process I think. I only found [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160823-00/?p=94145) on `Wait­On­Address`, but it barely touches on differences to SRW locks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an uncontended state an SRWLock is just an atomic `int`. So it's unsurprising that it performs the same as an `atomic`.

You should see very different timings once you introduce some contention in your tests.

An SRWLock is essentially a Windows version of a [futex](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html) - a synchronization primitive that remains fully in user-space until a contention occurs.

`Wait­On­Address` / `Wake­By­Address` and SRWLock are very similar internally, but the use-case is different - SRWLock directly implements a `mutex`/`shared_mutex` and `Wait­On­Address` / `Wake­By­Address` are more useful for `condition_variable`.